# TransactionScope locks table when connection timeout

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope, sql-server-2016

We have a transactionscope in our WebAPI project which performs 2 operations - Operation1 & Operation2. We also have a retry option for Operation2 when it times out because of table lock. In one of the scenario when one db call for operation2 times-out and if it succeeds in second attempt, then both the operations performed are not committed or rollbacked. The tables are in locked state in database. Below is the code structure,

```
//TransactionScope in Main method
TransactionScope scope= new TransactionScope()
{
 Operation1();
 Operation2();
 scope.commit();
}

//First operation method
public void Operation1()
{
 sqlconnection conn= new sqlConnection(connectionstring);
 try
 {
  conn.open();
  cmd = new sqlcommand(conn);
  //Executes successfully
  cmd.executenonquery();
 }
 finally
 {
  conn.close();
 }
}

//Second operation method
public void Operation2()
{
 //Assume that the first time db call in forloop failed because of timeout
 //and the second time call succeeded
 for(int I=0;i<2;i++)
  {
   sqlconnection conn= new sqlConnection(connectionstring);
   try
   {
    conn.open();
    cmd = new sqlcommand(conn);
    cmd.executenonquery();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
     if(e.Message != "Connection Timeout")
     {
       Throw e;
     }
   }
   finally
   {
    conn.close();
   }
  }
}
```

In this case when Opearion1 succeeds and Opeartion2 succeeds in the 2nd for loop call, then both the transactions are not getting committed or rolledback. Will the transactionscope gets abandoned if any SQL error or timeout occurs within the transactionscope code?

Comment: Try using just one connection that you create outside the transaction scope.

Comment: You should use: `using (TransactionScope scope= new TransactionScope()
) { ...}`

Comment: I am using the using statement as well. In normal scenario it is working fine. But only when one Db call timeout and succeed after retry it is failing